# How do i create a variable in tk.write()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie to python and stack overflow.How do we create a variable in the tkinter.write() function in python. the below object is my code.

```
import turtle as t
import itertools as it
import random
import tkinter as tk


def new_func():
    user_num = input("Type any number from 1-10 below")
    return user_num

user_num = new_func()
computer_num = random.randint(1,10)
t.fillcolor("red")
t.begin_fill()
t.color("red")
a= 4
for _ in it.repeat(None,a) :
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
t.end_fill()
t.write(user_num)
while user_num != computer_num :
    if user_num > computer_num :
        print("To high")
        user_num = input("type again : ")
    elif user_num < computer_num :
        print("To low")
        user_num = input("type again : ")
    else :
        print("Yay! you guessed it!")
```

Comment: `tkinter` has no function called `write`. What do you mean by `tkinter.write()`?

Comment: Actually your application is a console application which does not require tkinter (or turtle) at all.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing *tkinter* isn't needed for this.  Possibly, if you have advanced canvas requirements later on, but for now, it can all be done within the Turtle script.  Your loop wouldn't loop that way.  It needs to be wrapped within your new function, so that it can be called again, when required.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import turtle as trt
import itertools as it
from time import sleep
import random

t, screen = trt .Turtle(),  trt .Screen()
screen .title( 'Take a guess' )

fontname = 'Arial'  ##  anytime you use a single equal sign, you are assigning a value to a variable.
fontsize = 33  ##  larger fontsize
fontstyle = 'normal'
f = ( fontname, fontsize, fontstyle )

computer_num = random .randint( 1, 10 )

##  wrap all your instructions in here, so that when you call new
def new_func():  ##  it can repeat from this point

    ##  turtle has a numinput box that ensures player types numbers
    ##  instead of letters, and lets you specify min / max values
    
    popup_title = 'Guess'
    message = 'Type any number from 1-10'
    default_value = 5

    ##  wrap it in an int, to get rid of decimal points
    user_num = int( screen .numinput( popup_title,  message,  default_value, minval = 1,  maxval = 10 ) )

    t .penup()
    t .clear()
    t .goto( -50, -25 )  ##  so when you jump turtle back home(), text is centered
    t .fillcolor( 'red' )
    t .begin_fill()
    t .color( 'red' )
    t .pendown()
    a = 4

    for _ in it .repeat( None, a ) :
        t .fd( 100 )
        t .lt( 90 )
    t .end_fill( )

    t .penup()
    t .home()
    t .color( 'black' )  ##  set to a diff' color than background, for readability

    t .write( user_num,  align = 'center',  font = f )
    t .penup()
    t .sety( -100 )
    t .pendown()

    if user_num > computer_num :
        t .write( 'Too high',  align = 'center',  font = f )
        sleep( 1 )
        new_func()  ##  call it, to start the loop again

    elif user_num < computer_num :
        t .write( 'Too low',  align = 'center',  font = f )
        sleep( 1 )
        new_func()

    else :
        t .write( 'Yay! you guessed it!',  align = 'center',  font = f )
        t .hideturtle()
        sleep( 3 )

new_func()  ##  call the function once, so it can begin.
```

Comment: 2 things: can you please look over [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and doesn't `sleep` cause the window to stop responding? I know `turtle` is based off of `tkinter` and using `sleep` causes the window to stop responding. I am just guessing but doesn't that happen when using `turtle`?

Comment: *PEP8* doesn't change the fact that this *actually runs correctly*.  And if you had tried it, you wouldn't be complaining about a 3 second pause to display text before closing the window.

Comment: Just tried it and it's bad practise to leave your windows unresponsive. Look at `tkinter` `.after` scripts. I am sure that you can access that method from your `turtle.Screen()` object. Also PEPs are designed to make your code more readable.

Comment: I'll look at it later, not seeing one listed.  `import tkinter as tk ; print( tk .after )` -- `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'after'`

Comment: It's not a `tkinter` function but instead a method that exists in all `tkinter` widgets/windows. Use `<turtle.Screen object>._root._canvas.after(time_delay_in_ms, function_to_call)`. It calls the function specified after the delay. Note that the delay is in milliseconds. So instead of `sleep(1)` and `new_func()`, use `screen._root._canvas.after(1000, new_func)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an f-string,

And there is no tkinter.write() function, You can use the Text or Label class in Tkinter

Example of text class:

`some_variable = Text(tkinter_window, bg, fg, border, height, width, font, etc..`

You can view all the parameters here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-text-widget/

Then after that you can `some_variable.insert(index, f"{variable_name} text")`

The indexes are available in the Tkinter module, An example would be END

Example of label class:

```
some_variable = Label(window, text=f"{variable_name} text")
```

Comment: `tkinter` has no `write` function. Also I don't think OP would be able to use this answer.

Comment: Yep, @TheLizzard, Updated the answer based on that..

Comment: Why did you assume that OP wanted to show text? Also would `tk.Label` be more suitable? In cases like this it's better to ask OP what they meant before writing an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by OP, and yes we can use the Label Class too

Comment: OP = Original Poster. Basically the person who asked the question

Comment: Oh, Fine, @TheLizzard, Also updated the answer